# Expressing IS NOT NULL without causing a PEP8 error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pep8

At a certain point in my project, I need to query a SQLAlchemy object for columns that are NOT NULL. In my code, I do:

```
session.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.my_column != None).all()
```

...and it works great. Problem is, whenever I run `pep8` or one of the other linters on the file, it raises an error E711: Comparison to `None` should be `if cond is not None:`. I agree with the spirit of this guideline, and as such I don't want to silence the warning just because of one little line.

Is there another way to write this? Preferably one where we don't have to dig into the `func` module?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

PEP8 isn't meant to be followed to the letter.

You're *recommended* to use `is None` instead of `== None` because `is` cannot be overloaded (unlike `==`):

```
>>> class Bad(object):
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return True
...
>>> instance = Bad()
>>> instance == None
True
>>> instance is None
False
```

In your case you *want* to use the overloaded `==` operator, so the warning is incorrect.

There are three ways of making the warning go away:

1. You can disable that particular warning for that single line:

   - For Flake8/PyFlakes:

     ```
     session.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.my_column != None).all()  # noqa: E711
     ```
   - For Pylint:

     ```
     session.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.my_column != None).all()  # pylint: disable=singleton-comparison
     ```
2. You can avoid using the equality operator by directly calling the class's `__eq__` (for `==`) and `__ne__` (for `!=`) methods:

   ```
   session.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.my_column.__ne__(None)).all()
   ```
3. You can use [`.is_`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.is_) and [`.isnot`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.isnot):

   ```
   session.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.my_column.isnot(None)).all()
   ```

   Note that `.is_` and `.isnot` are not the same as `==` and `!=`. `MyModel.my_column != x` can mean both `IS NOT NULL` and `!= x` depending on the value of `x` and your database, so solutions 1 and 2 are probably better unless you really don't like using `__`-methods and know the type of the right-hand-side of your expression.

Comment: That `# noqa` marker is handy! I'm glad I know about it now.

Comment: Thanks, Blender. For reference, here's a link to the specific location in the docs where this is described: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.isnot

Comment: Thanks for not only giving your preferred answer but also an alternative for people with OCD-like behavior (me) that don't want to use `# noqa`.

Comment: To disable only that specific warning use `# pylint: disable=singleton-comparison`

Comment: @SteveSaporta: Thanks. I'm not sure where I got E222 from.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can also circumvent the verification by using a reference to `None` instead of `None` itself:

```
NULL = None

def query_stuff():
    ...
    session.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.my_column != NULL).all()
```